# Create network shares via command line with specific permissions

Tags: command-line, network-shares, windows-server-2003

This is sort of a two-pronged question.

I am developing an application that will need to be able to create network shares in Windows Server 2003 via the command line. So, firstly, how do I create shares in Windows via the command line? I tried researching it, and all I was able to find is that I should be using `net`, but other than that, there isn't much documentation.

Also, in this share there will be a few directories with the names of users on the domain, and I would like for the directories to not be readable or writable by anyone else. For example, say I have two directories: `jsmith` and `jdoe`. I would like the user `jsmith` to write and read from the directory `jsmith`, but not the directory called `jdoe`, and vice versa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be the information that you are looking for:

```
::Create a drive letter map to an existing network share
net use z: \\servername\share password /USER:domain\username /PERSISTENT:YES

:: grant user 'jsmith' full control access to the jsmith directory
cacls z:\jsmith /T /E /G jsmith:f
```

You can also remove permissions, or edit permissions on the directory using cacls.exe. My recommendation would be to read up on cacls.exe

**Cacls**

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490872.aspx

or just "cacls /?" from the command line should work as well.

Comment: PERSIST_E_NT ;)

Comment: What does the option "/PERSISTENT:YES" ?

Comment: From Microsoft (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/gg651155(v%3Dws.11)):

Controls the use of persistent network connections. The default is the setting used last. Deviceless connections are not persistent. Yes saves all connections as they are made, and restores them at next logon. No does not save the connection being made or subsequent connections. Existing connections are restored at the next logon. Use /delete to remove persistent connections.

Comment: Follow up for anyone using Windows 10: "cacls.exe" has been deprecated in favor of "icacls.exe" which does much the same thing.

Answer (score 11):

The command you're looking for is `net share`. The `/?` help on the command is pretty straightforward, but here is an example:

```
net share MyShareName="C:\My Local Path\SomeFolder" /GRANT:Everyone,FULL
```

As far as security goes, from what I've read, the best-practice is to do as above, grant the Everyone group full control on the ***share***, and then manage the permissions on the files and folders themselves. This is because the share permissions are a restriction filter over top of the actual file and folder permissions.